# Visual Studio command line build arguments

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, build

When i build my project from Visual Stutio UI (Debug Configuration) and set the option:
Tools->Options->Project and Soulutions->Build and run-> MSBuild output verbosity to "Normal", in the output window i get the build command:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Vbc.exe /noconfig
>   /imports:Microsoft.VisualBasic,System,System.Collections,System.Collections.Generic,System.Data,System.Drawing,System.Diagnostics,System.Windows.Forms,System.Linq,System.Xml.Linq
>   /optioncompare:Binary /optionexplicit+ /optionstrict:custom
>   /nowarn:41999,42016,42017,42018,42019,42020,42021,42022,42030,42032,42036,42104,42108,42109,42353,42354,42355
>   /optioninfer+ /nostdlib /platform:x86 /removeintchecks-
>   /rootnamespace:INFOPRIM
>   /sdkpath:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 /highentropyva-
>   /doc:obj\Debug\INFOPRIM.xml
>   /define:"CONFIG=\"Debug\",DEBUG=-1,TRACE=-1,_MyType=\"WindowsForms\",PLATFORM=\"AnyCPU\""
>   /reference:C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\adodb\7.0.3300.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\adodb.dll,"C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework
>   4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll","C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework
>   4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.dll","C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework
>   4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.dll",

etc. And a lot more. It's every *.vb file and resource in the project.

What I want to know if it's the equivalent to :

> devenv.exe MyProject.sln /build Debug /project "MyProject.vbproj"
>   /projectconfig Debug

Because I need to build from command line.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If possible, for automated builds you should use MSBuild instead of Visual Studio.

```
msbuild MyProject.vbproj /t:Build /p:Configuration=Debug /verbosity:normal
```

(could also be quiet, minimal and diagnostic)

Comment: This command worked very well for my project.  I ran it from the command line with the working directory being the directory containing the project file.  I had a VS2010 and a Visual C++.NET project, so my project file ended in .vcxproj rather than .vbproj

I used the MSBuild.exe program specifically for .NET version 4 (matching my project), which on my system was located at:
    C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe